# How to use Cordova with Samsung Gear 2?

Tags: cordova, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

I know you can make html5 web apps in Tizen wearables IDE for gear 2, but is Cordova compatible with this? I can't find any documentation at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't personally played around with Cordova on gear 2, but I think another approach you can use is similar to their consumer-provider example where they communicate via SamsungAccessoryProtocol. You can send messages from the phone to the watch, so you can send a html message through and write some javascript code that injects the html into your application.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Cordova plugin that wraps the SamsungAccessoryProtocol. https://github.com/tgardner/cordova-galaxygear

Gives you simple bidirectional communication.